# Ruby syntax with quotes

Tags: ruby, syntax, quotes

I have the following statement in my ruby code

```
curlsyntax = "URL = "

restcall = 'http://myurl.com/File?schema=1.5&token=' + auth_token + '&product=http://myurl.com/Product/8283&form=json&productname=http://myurl.com/name/' + productname + '&priority=now'

call = curl + restcall
```

What thats giving me is a quote at the beginning of my final out ie "URL = http... but I don't actually want that first quote to show up it should be URL = "http

Comment: You could always use the [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem instead of having to make an external call to `curl`.

Answer (score 3):

The quote you are seeing before URL is simply how ruby represents a string - it's not actually part of the string.  To add double quotes before and after `restcall`, you can do this:

```
call = "#{curlsyntax}\"#{restcall}\""
```

Comment: Or, to avoid escaping the quotation marks: `call = %{#{curlsyntax}"#{restcall}"}`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
call = %{URL = "#{restcall}"}
```

But you should probably use something like http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html for safe system calls. Example:

```
require 'open3'
require 'shellwords'

command = Shellwords.shelljoin(['curl', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3({'ENV1' => 'value1', 'ENV2' => 'value2'}, command)

result = stdout.read
```

That way you can safely escape arguments passed to the command line and even pass environment variables to your call.

Comment: @theTinMan I figured he wanted to call cURL on the CLI with the string he's building. Open3 gives you more flexibility when it comes to env variables and such. Might not be necessary in this scenario though, that's true :)

Comment: In that case he should use the Curb gem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe to build such queries by hand. I would opt for using something like this: https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable

Comment: Or Ruby's own [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), with its warts and all.